# Extracting specific links using PHP preg_match_all

Tags: php, curl, preg-match-all

I have an html file containing

```
 <img width="10" height="12" scr="https://www.site.com/yughggcfgh">
<img width="11" height="15" scr="https://www.site.com/yughggcfghcvbcvb">
<img width="10" height="12" scr="https://www.site.com/a.jpg">
<img width="10" height="12" scr="https://www.site.com/b.gif">
```

I want to extract the paths of images which doesn't have an extention in an array,
 The output must be as follows

```
ari[1]= <img width="10" height="12" scr="https://www.site.com/yughggcfgh">
ari[2]= <img width="11" height="15" scr="https://www.site.com/yughggcfghcvbcvb">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Comment: I think you have a typo `scr=` → `src=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should use [domDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or some html parser not regex heres an example:

```
<?php 
$somesource='<img width="10" height="12" src="https://www.site.com/yughggcfgh">
<img width="11" height="15" src="https://www.site.com/yughggcfghcvbcvb">
<img width="10" height="12" src="https://www.site.com/a.jpg">
<img width="10" height="12" src="https://www.site.com/b.gif">';

$xml = new DOMDocument();
@$xml->loadHTML($somesource);
foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    if(substr($img->getAttribute('src'),-4,1)!='.'){
        $image[] = $img->getAttribute('src');
    }
}

print_r($image);

Array
(
    [0] => https://www.site.com/yughggcfgh
    [1] => https://www.site.com/yughggcfghcvbcvb
)

?>
```

Comment: Maybe be more restrictive as to what constitutes an _image extension_

Comment: I noted its an example, im not here to complete scripts for peeps but only give examples to build appon ;p

Comment: Thanks it works ! is domDocument will work on every PHP server ??

Comment: @Alfredfrancis Yes any server with PHP 5. Dont forget to scan through the documentation.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: well… fair enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are probably not the right tool for the job, but here you go …

You should be able to achieve your goal with [negative lookbehind assertions](http://php.net/regexp.reference.assertions):

```
preg_match_all('/src=".+?(?<!\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.png)"/', $html, $matches);
```

Comment: error : Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\index.php on line 19