# Extracting specific links using PHP from html page

Tags: php, regex, curl, preg-match, domdocument

I have a HTML page containing follwing links

```
<a class="out" href="www.a.com/hgfgtsdfdffsdfsdf">sdfsssdfddf</a>
<a href="www.a.com/hgfgt">dsfdsf</a>
<a class="menu" href="www.a.com/hgfgt">menu1</a>
<a class="menu" href="www.a.com/hgfgdfg">menu2</a>
<a class="menu" href="www.a.com/hgfgdfg">menu3</a>
<a href="www.a.com/hgfgtssdfdfsdf">sdfsdfddf</a>
<a href="www.a.com/hgfgtsdfsfsdfdf">sdfsdfsddf</a>
<a href="www.a.com/hgfgtsdfsdfsdf">sdfsdfddf</a>
<a class="out" href="www.a.com/hgfgtsdfsdfsdf">sdfsdfddf</a>
```

I want to extract the links and their titles of the class "menu" to an array using PHP,please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting specific links using PHP preg_match_all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010503/extracting-specific-links-using-php-preg-match-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '<a class="out" href="www.a.com/hgfgtsdfdffsdfsdf">sdfsssdfddf</a>
<a href="www.a.com/hgfgt">dsfdsf</a>
<a class="menu" href="www.a.com/hgfgt">menu1</a>
<a class="menu" href="www.a.com/hgfgdfg">menu2</a>
<a class="menu" href="www.a.com/hgfgdfg">menu3</a>
<a href="www.a.com/hgfgtssdfdfsdf">sdfsdfddf</a>
<a href="www.a.com/hgfgtsdfsfsdfdf">sdfsdfsddf</a>
<a href="www.a.com/hgfgtsdfsdfsdf">sdfsdfddf</a>
<a class="out" href="www.a.com/hgfgtsdfsdfsdf">sdfsdfddf</a>';

preg_match_all('#<a class="menu" href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)#', $str, $m);

var_dump($m[1], $m[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('#<a class="menu" href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</a>#', $content, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with DOMDocument and XPath:

```
$html = '

<a class="out" href="www.a.com/hgfgtsdfdffsdfsdf">sdfsssdfddf</a>
<a href="www.a.com/hgfgt">dsfdsf</a>
<a class="menu" href="www.a.com/hgfgt">menu1</a>
<a class="menu" href="www.a.com/hgfgdfg">menu2</a>
<a class="menu" href="www.a.com/hgfgdfg">menu3</a>
<a href="www.a.com/hgfgtssdfdfsdf">sdfsdfddf</a>
<a href="www.a.com/hgfgtsdfsfsdfdf">sdfsdfsddf</a>
<a href="www.a.com/hgfgtsdfsdfsdf">sdfsdfddf</a>
<a class="out" href="www.a.com/hgfgtsdfsdfsdf">sdfsdfddf</a>

';

$classname = 'menu'; // class to find

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$result = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

foreach($result as $elem)
{
    echo "title: " . $elem->nodeValue . "<br />";
    echo "link: " . $elem->getAttribute('href') . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: showing error : 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag nobr invalid in Entity, line: 385 in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\l.php on line 20

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 385 in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\l.php on line 20

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 385 in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\l.php on line 20

Comment: DOMDocument is picky about HTML. In this case you can supress the warning using the @ sign for the loadHTML() call, like: `@$doc->loadHTML($html);`